# Blank space after Facebook iframe videos on mobile version

Tags: facebook, video, iframe, space

I've been looking for a way to fix this, by searching here, but no fix would work for it !

I'm running into an issue with Facebook iframe video integrated on my website ! (a blog)

It's displaying ok on desktop version but, when resizing the window, or going on mobile version, there is HUGE blank space created below the iframe. It is INSIDE the iframe and I have no control over it.

[Desktop version looking fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZApnG.jpg)

[Mobile version with HUGE blank space below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8HrG.jpg)

Here is the iframe :

```html
<iframe class="iframe" style="border: none; overflow: hidden;"
        src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fsalutparisfr%2Fvideos%2Fvb.1523831884576352%2F1642593346033538%2F%3Ftype%3D3&amp;show_text=0&amp;width=400"
        width="600" height="460" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"
        allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
```

Here is the CSS code :

```css
.iframe {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Note: changing values in the iframe code didn't do the trick
Deleting all iframe css classes didn't do it either !

Tried changing the heigh value of the iframe to "100%", this is what it turned out :

[Desktop version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrGVH.jpg)

[Mobile version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmFrW.jpg)

It seems like facebook iframe is broken internally ?! My Vimeo and Youtube iframes work perfectly...

Any idea about this ?

Thanks !

Comment: Did you find the answer ? Still facing this issue in 2020..